# Efficient way to write test cases depending on a Micro service

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I'm very new to microservice architecture. In the Monolithic app structure, it was pretty straightforward to write test cases since everything was in one app. I have a situation where I manage a microservice (built on FastAPI) that stores only the users with different types like company, admin, student etc Then there's a microservice called company that stores all the company-related operations like storing jobs, hiring candidates etc. Currently, my application fetches some jobs from company microservice based on company id.

When writing test cases for the endpoint on my app that calls the endpoint on the company microservice for fetching jobs, I'm basically actually calling their endpoint in a test to test if everything is going well. I know that I can mock data but it's not efficient imo. What if the company microservice changes some response schema and my response schema was modelled after them. So, now my test is succeeding but the actual endpoint is failing.

However, I'm new so I don't know what is optimal. I've done some research, and one was saying about sociable testing, which is the real endpoint since it has more reliability.

**So, what's the optimal way to test such situations? I'm willing to learn different ways. Thank you.**

I researched on the internet and found some ways but I'm willing to see what the community has to suggest.

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76024125/efficient-way-to-write-test-cases-depending-on-a-micro-service "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: Show us your code. Tell us about the [contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) the Company μservice is bound by. Is it [versioned](https://semver.org)? What aspect of the Company response is important to the target code which relies on it, and how does your unit test verify such aspects? What response changes have historically happened or you fear might happen, and how does your test try to call out such changes?

Answer (score 2):

There are a limited number of categories of tests you can perform in any environment. Some are not appropriate for certain types of software because the software needs to already working when in production (finance, aviation, medical come to mind). Others benefit from the possibility to run with an approximation.

I'm currently reading [Efficient Go by Bartłomiej Płotka](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1098105710) which has Figure 7.2 representing the effectiveness of a test against the amount of effort necessary to write said test. *Note that the book is much more about benchmarking & profiling, but it does touch on the subject of tests used for correctness: unit tests and some type of integration tests.*

[image]

### Unit Tests

In your question, I think you described a Unit Test. These are pretty effective and require little effort. These would be tests that mock any connection to another microservice. For correctness (since you do not properly define what you mean by "efficient", I will assume it is mainly correctness), these are the best tests you can come up with. The mocking can mock every case you can think of: perfect connection, connection timeout, mangled data returned, lost connection midway, etc.

### Integration Testing

The other type of testing is called Integration Testing. The graph presents two types: End to End and Production. I personally prefer End to End because you can run it on your own test system without disturbing your customers. If you have a very fast way to rolling back and disturbing customers for a short period of time won't break your business, then Production is the best in term of effectiveness (which in the graph means: fastest way to determine/find issues in your software). However, production testing has drawbacks as mentioned below.

#### End to End Integration Testing

End to End Integration testing is, I think, what you are looking for: run tests against the entire system including all the microservices. In this case, you want to setup a test system with all the services running simultaneously and run a battery of tests to see that it works as expected. Here you have all the usual problems: you want to mock the data so that way you can compute in advance what the results must be. You want to verify that when a microservice dies and restarts, that the main app. is still responsive (quickly reconnects automatically). End to End Integration testing allows you to also do full, or at least close to full coverage of your application.

Where complexity arise is in testing all error cases. As you mentioned, it could fail connecting to the microservice. It could connect and return erroneous data or only half the data. How do you test all of that is more and more complicated as your application grows. However, you should think of an RPC (or whatever you call gather data from a microservice at your place) as an equivalent to a local function call. The type of returned results are very similar. What you have in addition are all the potential network errors.

#### Production Integration Testing

Production Integration testing is running your application in production with users actually testing for you. There is, I think, a huge disadvantage: the app. may stop working altogether... that can cost you. But another even more important issue to keep in mind with this type of testing: you are not going to test the obscure passes of your application. Some error cases may be badly handled and not triggered even after hours of Production testing. In any event, the way to make this possible is most often to use a feature flag. Turn on the feature at various times of the day, see what happens, turn it back off. Analyze the data. Fix issues if any... Repeat.

And as mentioned above, don't do that for applications that involve any type of financial, health, and similar risks. Those applications must be tested End to End and Unit tested as well.

### Which to chose?

The best is to have all of them. But that's generally not feasible. So in most cases you end up with unit tests which offer as much coverage as possible and End to End or Production testing.

**So to answer your question: do both.**

Comment: Hi, thank you. Currently, it's what I'm doing. My test cases actually call other microservice endpoint. I want to be sure that my code actually works rather than just mocking data. This way if anything in their code breaks which end up breaking my test cases, I can at least inform them. @Alexis

Comment: @KoushikDas Oh, I see. They would be responsible for their own Unit Tests for their mircroservices. On your end, you then make sure things work together. Although you could have your own Unit Tests with mocks, but if your code is more like a very basic shell, it makes sense to do it as you describe.